# TSQL Msg 1013 "Use correlation names to distinguish them."

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I looked trough many suggestions and can't figure how to solve this one for the last two hours.

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY

DECLARE @Source DATETIME = '01/01/2001'
DECLARE @Destenaition DATETIME = '01/01/2020'

SELECT ST.[Group],
       ST.Shop,
       SUM(ST.Purchased) AS Total,
       CHG.Charged
FROM   (SELECT Personals.Groups.[Name]      AS 'Group',
               Cards.vPurchases.PersonalID,
               Personals.Registry.[Name],
               SUM(Cards.vPurchases.Ammont) AS Purchased,
               Cards.vPurchases.ShopName    AS Shop
        FROM   Cards.vPurchases
               INNER JOIN Personals.Registry
                 ON Personals.Registry.Id = Cards.vPurchases.PersonalID
               INNER JOIN Personals.Groups
                 ON Personals.Registry.[Group] = Personals.Groups.Id
               INNER JOIN Personals.Groups
                 ON Personals.Groups.Id = CHG.GroupID
        WHERE  Cards.vPurchases.[TimeStamp] >= @Source
               AND Cards.vPurchases.[TimeStamp] <= @Destenaition
        GROUP  BY Cards.vPurchases.PersonalID,
                  Personals.Registry.[Name],
                  Personals.Groups.[Name],
                  Cards.vPurchases.ShopName) ST,
       (SELECT PG.Id                      AS GroupID,
               SUM(Cards.vCharges.Amount) AS Charged
        FROM   Cards.vCharges
               INNER JOIN Personals.Registry
                 ON Personals.Registry.Id = Cards.vCharges.PersonalID
               INNER JOIN Personals.Groups AS PG
                 ON Personals.Registry.[Group] = PG.Id
        WHERE  Cards.vCharges.[TimeStamp] >= @Source
               AND Cards.vCharges.[TimeStamp] <= @Destenaition
        GROUP  BY Personals.Groups.[Name]) AS CHG
GROUP  BY ST.Shop,
          ST.[Group]
```

And then I get this error:

> Msg 1013, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 The objects "Personals.Groups" and
>   "Personals.Groups" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use
>   correlation names to distinguish them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using the table `Personals.Groups` two times in the first sub query.
If you really mean to have the table `Personals.Groups` you need to give them an alias that you then use instead of the table names in the rest of the query.

```
INNER JOIN Personals.Groups as PG1
```

and

```
INNER JOIN Personals.Groups as PG2
```

If you only need one you can combine the `on` clauses to use just one instead.

```
INNER JOIN Personals.Groups 
  ON Personals.Registry.[Group] = Personals.Groups.Id and
     Personals.Groups.Id = CHG.GroupID
```